# What is a good & free game engine?

Tags: java, c++, python

For C++, Java, or Python, what are some good game + free game engines that are easy to pick up?

Any type of game engine is okay. I just want to get started somewhere by looking into different game engines and their capabilities.

Comment: You should perhaps indicate if your primary interest is in doing a 2D game, or a full-on 3D game. It might affect the set of available engines, as engines are often specialized in this respect.

Comment: Depends entirely on the kind of game. Inform 7 is awesome for text adventures.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For my Computer Graphics course in College we used the open source [OGRE 3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) engine.  Not only is this an extremely robust 3D engine but it was a blast!

Develop a medium sized game using it and you will get a good taste of many of the different [game programming specialties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programmer). You'll find yourself doing 3d modeling, sound effects, physics programming, AI, the works.

[alt text http://www.mactabilisarts.com/Images/multiplayer%20games.jpg](http://www.mactabilisarts.com/Images/multiplayer%20games.jpg)
*Screenshot of a recent OGRE 3D Game*

Comment: wakey wakey ;) Time to go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309517 and vote to reopen. Great picture/link by the way. +1

Comment: Ogre3D is the way I'd go. I'd be focusing almost totally on C++ game development, also.

Comment: there is also PyOgre, if you want to code in python and still use the ogre3d engine.

Answer (score 14):

Java hasn't got any love here? For 2D and 3D OpenGL on win/mac/linux/android, try [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). For 2D with API similar to Java2D try [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/). [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) for pure OpenGL bindings. [Ardor3D](http://www.ardor3d.com/) or [JMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) for a higher level 3D library. For networking, [KryoNet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/).

Comment: You've forgotten JOGL: http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html)  It has work well for me in the past.  It is very easy to use and comes with the bonus of python :)

It has an active community and works on both Unix and Windows.  (I haven't tried it on Mac)

Comment: Pygame isn't a game engine.  It lets you write a game engine but it's not a game engine in and of itself.

Comment: I will accept that, but there a few that are based on it http://www.pygame.org/tags/engine

Comment: Thanks for thís, I'm looking for a good python game engine :)

Answer (score 5):

For python game development I would look into using [panda3d](http://panda3d.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Not really the language you want but I still think it's a good engine: [Löve](http://www.love2d.org/), and it's written in [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).

Answer (score 3):

**Python**

I've ditched Pygame and started using [Pyglet](http://pyglet.mirror.codeflow.org/).

It is extremely easy to play around with, it is nicely complete (OpenGL, mp3 support, image formats, joystick...), and it has a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ready for deeper mechanics but greater freedom, have a look at [Crystal Space](http://www.crystalspace3d.org/main/Main_Page) (C++), if you want to use more already-prepared objects you can consider the [Irrlicht Engine](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) (C++ too).

Comment: Crystal Space is really too complicated for a first-time engine. Irrlicht is good though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/about) as well, it's rather extensive, cross-platform and you can add functionality like physics through existing add-ons - or write your own in C++. It is however a graphics engine, rather than a dedicated game engine, but the add-ons amend that.

More importantly there are wrappers for Python ([Python-Ogre](http://www.python-ogre.org/)), Java ([ogre4j](http://ogre4j.sourceforge.net/)) and .Net ([MOGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/MOGRE)).

Answer (score 1):

I heard good things about [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), but i haven't used it myself.

In a completely different area, i think [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) has been complemented with interaction capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Many open source projects are hosted on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/), some are games, and some of those use a 3rd party engine. Maybe you could have a look there?

Answer (score 1):

[Garry's Mod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry's_Mod) was written using Half-Life 2's [Source engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_engine), presumably using the [Hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_Hammer_Editor) editor.

Granted, this is arguably closer to level design than game design, but might be interesting regardless.

Answer (score 1):

On the Java front, check out [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/).  It's got a lot of [features](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/wiki/doku.php?id=complete_features_list) including hardware acceleration using OpenGL.  I haven't attempted to develop anything using it, but I've been following the community for a while; they did a demo and presentation a few JavaOnes ago.

Moving from the client to the server, if you are interested in toolkits for building MMOGs, then check out [Project Darkstar](http://www.projectdarkstar.com/).  It's a server-side framework (written in Java) with client-side SDKs for Java and C.  The whole project is sponsored by Sun.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in 3D game programming, id Software of Doom and Quake fame often release the source code for their engines. You can find the source code for Quake I, II and III [here](http://www.idsoftware.com/business/techdownloads/) and a substantial chunk of the Doom 3 code [here](http://www.iddevnet.com/doom3/downloads.php) and Quake IV [here](http://www.iddevnet.com/quake4/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a RPG engine called VERGE if you're interested. Never tried it but I heard good things from it. 
I think it's in C++.