# What language should I write my 2D game in?

Tags: java, c++

I'm thinking of writing a game. It's inspired by Minecraft/Terraria (but don't worry it will be different).

My main question is what language I should write it in -- it'll be relatively simple graphics, more like Terraria than Minecraft. I know Java relatively well and Minecraft is written in it, but C++ seems like the industry standard for game development. However, I know next to no C++. I'm willing to learn but am worried how it will turn out for my first real project in the language.

In addition to that, I'd also like suggestions on a good game engine for the language that you suggest. I'd like it to run on:

- Windows for sure
- Linux for sure
- Mac for sure
- Android would be really nice
- iOS is optional

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you really want to press the cutting edge, write it in HTML5 and javascript. It will run in the browser, and you will learn a lot.

Comment: "Not a real question", but FWIW, I vote for Scala.

Comment: This is more suitable for [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Shakedown: Probably not.  It is just as OT there because they have a nearly identical FAQ/restriction on obviously open-ended questions.

Comment: @pst -- sorry :( I thought this was specific enough, seeing as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564469/what-is-a-good-free-game-engine) was a popular question.

Comment: @pst for the future, how is this question any different from the one I linked to above?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: You're right, but the point is to make the OP aware of "the stackoverflow specifically for game development" :)

Comment: @Shakedown: Definitely worth a mention.

Comment: @Shakedown thanks, but then why is there a [game-development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development) tag?

Comment: I closed the question you linked as Not Constructive, since it is a poll question (cannot be answered definitively) like this one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OK, I can see that this isn't the best question for SO now. sorry :P

Comment: @jmgrosen: No need to apologize.  You just don't know the rules yet.  You should check out the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq.  In my opinion people should just vote to close questions like this, not downvote them.  Also, you can opt to post here or on game dev.  There is no strict requirement that game dev questions are off topic here - just questions where any answer could be "correct".  People might vote to move your question to [gamedev.se] if it doesn't have much application outside game development, but that won't kill your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is the "industry standard" by heritage, by [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt), and (marginally now for 2D games) for performance reasons.

On the plus side for C++, you'd have more graphics, audio, and input library support.  Java doesn't have a lack of these types of libraries, but C++ has a glut of them.

On the negative side C++ is one of the least beginner-friendly languages out there, and even though there are multiple cross-platform libraries for it (e.g. SDL), it is not a cross-platform friendly language.

If you are more interested in spending the majority of your time making a *game* rather than a *game engine*, then I'd recommend you either write your engine in a higher level langauge, or use a pre-existing game engine and just script on top of it.

If you are more interested in spending the majority of your time making a *game engine* rather than a *game*, then maybe you should focus on making graphics demos, physics demos, or game content creation tools instead of games.  Those are all more directly applicable to learning what features a game engine would need to support and how they are implemented.

If you decide you must program both the engine and the game, you may want to look into embedding a scripting language into a C++ engine (such as [Lua](http://www.lua.org/)).  This is a very popular approach, taken by most games that support modding.  You don't have to support modding to use a scripting language, but most moddable games support modding through a scripting language.